# K8S EKS Cluster Autoscaler works without resources requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

In a K8S course I watched it was mentioned that Cluster Autoscaler can only work if you defined resources requests.

I deployed this yaml file (without resources requests & limits) to my EKS cluster, and I see that the autoscaler works pretty fine, it scales up and down even though I didn't define resources.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php-apache
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: php-apache
  replicas: 20    
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: php-apache
    spec:
     containers:
      - name: php-apache
        image: k8s.gcr.io/hpa-example
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
#        resources:
#          requests:
#           cpu: 999m
#           memory: 256Mi
#          limits:
#            cpu: 1000m
#            memory: 512Mi
```

[image]

My question is:

Is it really necessary to define resources requests for Cluster Autoscaler? If so, how come that I see the CA scales up and down in this case?

My goal is to find a way to skip the resource requests.
Developers in my company define very high resources requests and limits, which causes a waste of actual resources.

I though that if I remove the resources requests and limits, the CA will use the ACTUAL resources that the app needs, and not more than that as the developers define.

So if must define resources requests, how else can I solve the situation described above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What instance type do you use?

Comment: @Matt it alternates, currently I use m5.xlarge
4 vCPUs
16 GiB
EBS-Only
Up to 10 Gigabit

Comment: Did you check autoscaler logs? Can you add them to the question?

Comment: @Matt I can attach them but they are very long. Do you know if it makes sense to use autoscaler without resources requests?

Comment: It doesn't seem like a reasonable solution. At first I though the autoscaling may be cause by small instance with small pod count limit but its not the case: [eni-max-pods](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/blob/master/files/eni-max-pods.txt#L199). One more idea I have that could explain this behaviour is [limit-range](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/) which is capable to *"set default request/limit for compute resources in a namespace and automatically inject them to Containers at runtime"*, Can you confirm it?

Comment: @jrz I follow this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/autoscaling.html) to check logs autoscaler: 
`kubectl -n kube-system logs -f deployment.apps/cluster-autoscaler` 

And with my cluster this log when it scale out like this:

```
I0421 06:57:54.528251       1 scale_up.go:675] Scale-up: setting group <my-asg> size to 2
I0421 06:57:54.528317       1 auto_scaling_groups.go:219] Setting asg <my-asg> size to 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to low memory on the node, alas [Node-pressure Eviction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#node-out-of-memory-behavior).

The sequence of events is as follows (cluster events in quotes):

1. The eviction mechanism kicks in.

> The node was low on resource: memory. Container runner was using
> 1323680Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. Container dind was using
> 29104Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.

2. Containers get shut down.

> Stopping container 
> Stopping container

3. A `node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure` taint is added to the node.
4. Pod gets into an unschedulable (Pending) state, due to the taint and a lack of suitable nodes.

> 0/24 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had untolerated taint
> {node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure: }, 15 node(s) didn't match Pod's
> node affinity/selector, 8 node(s) had untolerated taint
> {platform/karpenter: }. preemption: 0/24 nodes are available: 24
> Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.

5. At this point, CA (Cluster Autoscaler) notices the pending Pod, and adds a new node to the ASG.

> Scale-up: setting group  size to 2